# How To Apply filter to List View Web Part based on content of Data View field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view, filter, data-view-web-part

I am building a project management tool. the top of each project page shows a List View webpart which displays information about the project's current status.

A second List View displays a Task List which I want to pre-load with the task sequence required by our project management methodology and then filter by Current Phase (displayed in the project info list) so that only the tasks applicable to the current project phase are displayed.

To accomplish this I think I need to find a way to alter the filter applied to the List View depending on the contents of the ProjectPhase field of the Project_Info list.

Does anyone have any ideas the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second list view web part to filter the first web part via list web part connection.

There is a blog about this similar topic for your reference:
[Creating Connected Web parts in SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/04/25/creating-connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint/)